# which beans should be declared in applicationContext and dispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Initially I declared all my beans in `dispatcher-servlet` and my application worked. Do I really need to have an `applicationContext.xml` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't necessarily need it, but it is a preferred way to separate application layers:

- in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` place only web-related stuff - controllers, view resolvers, converters, etc.
- in `applicationContext.xml` put all services and daos, and other general configurations

Note that you'll have to declare a listener so that spring can load `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then the context from `applicationContext.xml` will be the parent context, and the one in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` will be the child context. The child sees the beans in the parent, but the parent does not see those in the child.

Also note that `applicationContext.xml` is a default name. You can change the name or the path where it is seeked via the `contextConfigLocation` `<context-param>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `applicationContext.xml` file per-say. But you do need a xml file, even if it is only to tell Spring to auto-load all the beans in your application.